# Selecting maximum record

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I would like my query to only return count of chart points when the maximum chart version of each chart id is chart type Q. I want it to only count when it is chart type Q.

```
(CHART_ID,CHART_TYPE,CHART_VERSION,CNT)
(CHART1,Q,11,10)
(CHART1,Q,13,20)
(CHART1,I,14,5)

SELECT
    CHART_ID,
    CHART_TYPE,
    CHART_VERSION,
    COUNT(CHART_POINTS) AS CNT
FROM CHART_TABLE
WHERE
    CHART_TYPE = 'Q' AND 
    CHART_ID = 'CHART1'
GROUP BY
    CHART_ID,
    CHART_TYPE,
    CHART_VERSION
ORDER BY
    CHART_ID ASC
```

see query

It should return (CHART1,Q,13,20) for this chart id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one worked:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        CHART_ID,
        CHART_TYPE,
        CHART_VERSION,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN CHART_TYPE = 'Q' THEN 1 END) OVER
            (PARTITION BY CHART_ID, CHART_VERSION) CNT,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CHART_ID ORDER BY CHART_VERSION DESC) rn
    FROM CHART_TABLE
)

SELECT
    CHART_ID,
    CHART_TYPE,
    CHART_VERSION,
    CNT
FROM cte
WHERE
    rn = 1 AND CHART_TYPE = 'Q'
```

Comment: That is it! Is it possible to further restrict and not do chart point count if max chart version is not Q? In the example above it wouldn't return chart id and count since version 14 is the max but it is not Q. Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: I added additional conditional statement to count function per your recommendations and removed the group by clause and that gave me my secondary query. Thanks again!